# Edit with IDLE missing for Python 3.5.2. Python 2 not installed

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10

I can't seem to find a solution. I don't have Python 2.X or lower installed. I'm using Python 3.5.2 and I tried reinstalling, but the "Edit with IDLE" won't appear when I right click a .py file.
I'm Windows 10.

NOTE: Only doesnt appear for .py files. I just checked and it does appear for .pyw (Only difference is that I have notepad++ as default for .py)

Comment: The way "Edit with IDLE" is configured requires associating .py files with the `Python.File` program identifier (ProgId), which I recommend anyway to make scripts directly executable. You can add a secondary association in a subkey of `HKCU\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations` for Notepad++.

Comment: There are already some answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988880/set-python-idle-as-default-program-to-open-py-extensions. Check these out, good luck!

Comment: @KeeganKuhn, the OP wants "Edit with IDLE" back, not to make IDLE the default program for opening .py files.

Comment: @eryksun can you eli5 how I'd add it to registry please?

Comment: If you open it with IDLE, you can edit it then.

Comment: Do you want to associate .py files back to Python to get "Edit with IDLE" like that? Or do you want to leave Python files associated with Notepad++?

Comment: Make it Edit with IDLE for just .py is what I would like please. I use notepad++ for other random things.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear on what you want. If you don't want notepad++ for .py files, you can restore Edit with IDLE without directly modifying the registry. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43678126/205580). The reg.exe commands in that answer are just to inspect that everything is set up ok.

Comment: Ohhhhh! Thank you so much. I had no idea there was conflict :>